# Summing datatable in 1 linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this datatable :

[image]

I also have a class which contains two properties which should hold the sum for each Column :

```
class MyClass
{
 public decimal CatSum {get;set;}
 public decimal DogSum {get;set;}
}
```

I currently fill those props via :

```
 myClass.CatSum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r["Cat"].ToDecimalOrZero());
 myClass.DogSum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r["Dog"].ToDecimalOrZero())
```

Is there a way to fill (or create new class with those props) those props with *1 linq query* ?  ( I dont have any groupby field here)

;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use instance of `MyClass` as accumulator and aggregate results into it:

```
var myClass = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Aggregate(new MyClass(),
                           (a,r) => {
                                a.CatSum += r["Cat"].ToDecimalOrZero();
                                a.DogSum += r["DogS"].ToDecimalOrZero();
                                return a;
                           });
```

Comment: this works OK however I think the OP should go for 2 linq lines, it would be better.

Comment: @KingKing agree, two queries will be much more clear. This one is better only in terms of performance

Comment: This will scan the DT only one time...right ? ( as opposed to my solution and Dominic's ) please reply.

Comment: @RoyiNamir exactly, single enumerator will be created, and each row will be visited only once

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you're looking for performance (maybe you should state that in your question), then this is the best approach (besides a simple `foreach`-loop, of course).

Comment: @lazyberezovsky lol Im stealing your "loading..99%" ( now that youve changed yours... :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir :) yep, data is loaded, now rendering and displaying started

Answer (score 2):

A `Sum` is an aggregate query, you cannot use a single LINQ query to assign the 2 properties.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought also  that's why  mentioned that I dont have any groupby field....

Answer (score 1):

Why use Linq at all?

```
var myClass = new MyClass
{
    CatSum = (decimal)dt.Compute("SUM(Cat)", ""),
    DogSum = (decimal)dt.Compute("SUM(Dog)", "")
}
```